# Why does this Post work in VS, but not when published?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

In VS, this works fine:

```
http://x.x.x.x/Order/DeleteLineItem?id=c709d018-fd55-442c-9e0d-0826f98cf368
```

However, when published, and the app is run, it returns a 404 error.

It is being published to IIS 7.5.  All the rest of the app works fine, it's just those links which have an ID in them which are failing.

But the odd part is, in Visual Studio, in both FireFox and IIS, it works fine.  But outside of VS, they both give the same error message.

I have run it directly on the server for any additional error info, but it just says 404.

This doesn't make any sense to me.  Is there something else I should be doing to debug this?  At this point, the app doesn't have any error handling for 404 type of errors.

The Error Message says the Handler is "StaticFile" and the error code is: 0x80070002

Update

It turns out the issue was that the URL of the JQuery call was missing the site name.

This is what worked:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/PropertySearch/Order/EditLineItem",
        data: { id: dataItem.id },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#content').html(data); // 
        }
```

Comment: a lot more information is needed to help with this.  you haven't even stated what web server you are publishing to.

Comment: Yes, your right, I added more data.

Comment: do your ids match up to items that actually exist in the production database?

Comment: Can you please add the route definitions, and the DeleteLineItem action method code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason is that the environment you're publishing to requires SSL and you're using http rather than https.

The other possibility is that ASP.NET MVC isn't properly registered/configured in the deployment environment. Does the error message indicate it's using the StaticFile handler? Have you tried using Phil Haack's route debugger to get some insight to what's going on?

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/

Comment: Will check out the route debugger.  All the other MVC views are displayed normally, it's just the ones with the ID.  Perhaps it is because I am using a Guid as an Id.  I don't see why that would make a difference, but it makes no sense.

Comment: Not using SSL in this case.

Comment: I am fairly sure MVC is installed correctly as the app fires up and runs and navigates through a number of partial views.  It's only when it gets to a controller action that uses a GUID that there is a problem.  I am going to try switching to an int id instead.